# Custom Windows folder icon

Tags: windows, winapi

Skype has a nice custom folder icon for the Skype folder in C:\Program Files.

How do you do register a custom icon for a specific windows (XP and up) folder?

Comment: Huh? This is a question that C++ developers are most likely to have experience with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Skype's desktop.ini. It's a hidden file, you might have to enable Show hidden files to see it.

Comment: [.ShellClassInfo]
IconIndex=-910
IconFile=C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe

How do you register an icon?

Comment: " Set this entry to specify the index for a custom icon. If the file assigned to IconFile only contains a single icon, set IconIndex to 0."
An index where? How do I assign this an icon?

Comment: .exe and .dll files can have several icons embedded. In this case you have to specify which of the icons to use with IconIndex.

Answer (score 6):

[Customizing Folders with Desktop.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144102(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate API to customize folders. But you could use `WritePrivateProfileString` and `GetPrivateProfileString` functions to manage `desktop.ini` file.