# Get folder icon in python

Tags: python, windows, directory, icons

Is there any way to get a folder icon (Windows 10)?

I need to get the file/link/path to the folder icon with Python

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662759/how-to-change-folder-icons-with-python-on-windows?rq=4) how to change the icon, but I didn't find how to get it

I could not find packages to solve this problem.
Does anyone know how to do this with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system icons including the folder icon are stored in the following dll `%systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll` ([icon locations](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons/))

You could try extracting these icons using the python package [icoextract](https://pypi.org/project/icoextract/)