# Java - How to change icon of folder

Tags: java, windows, icons, directory

So how do I change the icon of a folder in Java (Windows system) is there a class or something cause I have searched and I can't find anything...

Comment: Do you mean the icons shown in the JFileChooser? Or the actual icon used for that folder by Windows, regardless of whether Java is involved?

Comment: You need to use the windows API. I don't know of any Java wrappers for that part of the API so you would have to make a small JNI program that calls the respective C function. I assume that you mean the icons inside the Windows explorer? Or if you mean individual folders then just use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115012/custom-windows-folder-icon

Comment: yes I mean my actual folders that I have so I need to tinker the hidden ini file in each folder to make it point to the icon that I want right?

Comment: @TheByt3 not every folder has that file. So if it's not there then you need to create it first. You can just write to it like a textfile but it would be better to use some kind of INI-Class or the Windows-API if you can tolerate JNI but that's probably overkill.

Comment: yea I'm kinda new to programming I just know how to code in java and c so I guess what you are telling me is that it's not that good to write into it like a text file or make it but better use an INI-Class (guess I can find that type of class in Java and C++ but I suppose it would be better in C++) or use the Windows-API which I have no idea what it is :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the folder icon that you are talking about is specified in a hidden "ini" file in the folder itself.

You *could* create / modify the file by reading it as text, etcera, but it is simpler to use an existing 3rd-party Java library.  I've had success using the open-source [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/) Java library.

Answer (score 0):

I did that using [ini4J](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/) and It is working with me under only one condition : Folder path shouldn't have any space.

The Code:

```
// Create destop.ini file 
writer = new BufferedWriter("your folder path without any spaces");
writer.write("");
writer.close();

// Set file attributes hidden and system and set folder as system folder and not hidden
Wini ini = new Wini("your folder path without any spaces");
String field = "icon Path" + ",0";
ini.put(".ShellClassInfo", "IconResource", field);
ini.store();
Process processCreateFile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +h +s " + "desktop.ini file path");
Process processCreateFolder = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -h +s " + "your folder path without any spaces");
```