# Changing an icon's folder by modifying desktop.ini

Tags: java, windows, file, attributes, ini

My goal is to change every folder's icon of my movie library to an icon I have for every folder in Windows using Java.

Every folder has a 256x256 icon in it named after the folder but with the appropriate extension.
For example the folder called *5cm Per Second* has the file *5cm Per Second.ico* in it.

I figured I could do this by modifying the *desktop.ini* file in the folder. All the folders have that file in them because the icons inside each folder used to be the actual icon of the folder, but after I changed the path of my movie library the path of the icon in *desktop.ini* didn't get updated.

Every *desktop.ini* looks like this:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]

IconResource=F:\Anime\Movies\5cm Per Second\5cm Per Second.ico,0
```

Now the path of where the icon is at is this: *E:\Movies\5cm Per Second\5cm Per Second.ico* so I figured all I have to do is change the *desktop.ini* to this:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]

IconResource=E:\Movies\5cm Per Second\5cm Per Second.ico,0
```

That did not work at all then I figured I also should make Windows know that *desktop.ini* is a system file, I added this to my code but that did not work at all.

My code for that sample folder:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.ini4j.Wini;

public class ListFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Directory path here
        String path = "E:\\Movies\\5cm Per Second";

        String fileName;
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                if ("ini".equals(getExtension(listOfFiles[i])))
                {
                    File theFile = listOfFiles[i];
                    Wini ini = new Wini(theFile);
                    String iconPath = theFile.getParent() + ".ico";
                    String field = iconPath + ",0";
                    ini.put(".ShellClassInfo", "IconResource", field);
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H " + theFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getExtension(File theFile) {
        String extension = null;
        String fileName = theFile.getName();
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (i > 0 && i < fileName.length() - 1) {
            extension = fileName.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
        }

        if (extension == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return extension;
    }
}
```

As you can see I edit the *IconResource* field to the one I need it to be using `ini4j` library and then I change the attributes of *desktop.ini* to Hidden and System.

It looks like this is not enough and I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: were you able to make this work without the library? By manually editing the .ini file?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330512/java-how-to-change-icon-of-folder

Comment: @jayan yes I am able to manually write in the ini file using notepad++, as for the related question I had asked the same thing but now that I have made progress I am only missing one thing, the reason for why ini4j doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling [ini.store()](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/OneMinuteTutorial.java.html), which probably writes the change to disk.