# How to add Icon To a folder using Java

Tags: java

I Want to create a folder and I want to attach a Icon to it.

```
File f=new File("");
f.mkdirs();
// f.addIcon() -- Is there any inbuilt method like this? Or any 3rd Party Lib?
```

Is there anyway how can I add icon to created folder on Windows System.

Comment: refer this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759709/changing-an-icons-folder-by-modifying-desktop-ini

Comment: this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330512/java-how-to-change-icon-of-folder

Comment: Obviously others got it; but maybe, just for the record you want to add some more information. Coming from a more unix-centered point of view, I am really wondering what it would mean to "add" an icon to a folder ;-)