# How to change directory icon using java

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am working in eclipse plugin application. I need to change existing directory icon in my project explorer. I am new in java. Any solution can be so helpful 
thanks in advance

[image]

```
File theFile=new File(selectedPath);
            Wini ini=new Wini(theFile);
            System.out.println("path== "+selectedPath);
            String field = "soc.gif" + ",0";
            ini.put(".ShellClassInfo", "IconResource", field);
            ini.store();
            System.out.println("path2== "+selectedPath);

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -h +s " + theFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

i am using above code to change directory icon but it show me exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: directory path (Access is denied)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - How to change icon of folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330512/java-how-to-change-icon-of-folder)

Comment: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html

Comment: File theFile=new File(selectedPath);
    Wini ini=new Wini(theFile);
    System.out.println("path== "+selectedPath);
    //String iconPath = theFile.getParent() + ".ico";
                String field = "soc.gif" + ",0";
                ini.put(".ShellClassInfo", "IconResource", field);
                ini.store();
                System.out.println("path2== "+selectedPath);
    
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -h +s " + theFile.getAbsolutePath());  I am using this code but is show in error in directory path