# create folder with app icon instead of default folder icon

Tags: java, android

I want to add my app Icon to created folder instead of default folder icon.

I know i can create folder with following code.

```
String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File mFolder = new File(extr + "/My Application/Downloads");
if (!mFolder.exists()) {
    mFolder.mkdirs();
}
```

**By doing this, i'm getting following result.**

[image]

**but what i want is..**

[image]

I have searched a lot, but no luck. can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: As I wrote ~2 years ago, directories do not have icons. You would need to talk to the developers of the app whose screenshot you are showing, and ask them "hey, how you are deciding what icon to show?" and see what they tell you. For example, the answer could be "if the directory's name is `Snapchat`, we show the Snapchat icon". Or, "if the directory is the `getExternalFilesDir()` directory for an app, we show that app's icon".

Comment: Are you sure that "Snapchat (4)" is a folder?
Did you try to make a folder with name "Snapchat"? What icon appeared for created by you folder?
There is a chance that file manager app changed icons for folder with some known app names.

Answer (score 8):

Directories do not have icons, and so whatever app or tool your screenshot is from is adding that. You would have to ask the developers of that app or tool what algorithm they are using to determine the icon to show.

Comment: well.. if i could contact developers of SnapChat that would be my first choice :D But thank you. +1 for Directories do not have icons.

Answer (score 0):

Customization of folder icon is OS dependent.

- On Windows you will use [Desktop.ini](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini) file to assign a custom icon or thumbnail image to a folder. To simplify working with Desktop.ini you can use [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/IniTutorial.java.html). Basically, you will need to create Desktop.ini in the folder, that you want to customize and specify path to the icon there. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330512/java-how-to-change-icon-of-folder) is similar question)
- On Mac OS the [process is different](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/create-custom-icons-files-folders-mac-mchlp2313/mac). There are ways to access icons (for example, [FileView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileView.html) or [FileSystemView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html), also [Quaqua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/javadoc/ch/randelshofer/quaqua/osx/OSXFile.html#getIcon%28java.io.File,%20int%29)). However I haven't found a way to set folder icon programmatically with Java.

<sub>Note: I assumed, that you want to add icon to arbitrary folder and not your app laucher.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

After creating new directory you have to declare resource directory in your gradle file so that android studio can recognize new resource directory.

More information please refer https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources